# changing debug to false causes styles not work

Tags: python, django

when I change DEBUG = False my page CSS styles not work.
also, I set allowed hosts but no difference made.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

I use djngo2.2 and here is part of my setting.py:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'matab',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'labsolutions.urls'
TEMPLATE_DIR= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/template/')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'labsolutions.wsgi.application'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/static/'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'statcifiles')
```

Comment: How have you deployed your app? You will need to run `collectstatic` and have a webserver serve your static files

Comment: @IainShelvington its local only.it works correctly with debug=True.but just changing it to False goes wrong!

Comment: You probably have a section in your `urls.py` that appends the debug static file serving view to your url patterns when DEBUG is true

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in developement and you want to serve the static while setting `DEBUG=False` then you need to launch the server using the insecure option
`python manage.py runserver --insecure`

Of course it is only valid for development